# Inconsistency with SVM in e1071 when using identical outcome values

Tags: r

I have a data frame testdf

> dput(testdf)

```
structure(list(X80 = c(0.0258, 0.0275, 0.0236, 0.0268, 0.0258, 
0.0261, 0.0346, 0.0278, 0.0289, 0.026, 0.0227, 0.0257, 0.0256, 
0.024, 0.0287, 0.029, 0.0218, 0.0254, 0.027, 0.0287, 0.0224, 
0.0226022602260226, 0.0271, 0.0271, 0.0295, 0.0256, 0.0258, 0.0294029402940294, 
0.0275, 0.03, 0.032, 0.0267, 0.0266, 0.0255, 0.0242, 0.0313, 
0.0291, 0.0294, 0.0254, 0.0254, 0.0262, 0.0255, 0.0261, 0.0232, 
0.0249, 0.0222, 0.0276, 0.0296, 0.0264, 0.0214, 0.0251, 0.0305, 
0.0279, 0.026, 0.0262, 0.0249, 0.0232), X81 = c(0.0057, 0.006, 
0.0049, 0.0063, 0.0053, 0.0056, 0.0057, 0.004, 0.0058, 0.0067, 
0.0058, 0.0057, 0.005, 0.0054, 0.0037, 0.006, 0.0065, 0.0064, 
0.0046, 0.0049, 0.0068, 0.0048004800480048, 0.0051, 0.0055, 0.0057, 
0.0074, 0.0065, 0.0053005300530053, 0.0053, 0.0057, 0.0046, 0.0053, 
0.0054, 0.0066, 0.0053, 0.0057, 0.0054, 0.0048, 0.0056, 0.0068, 
0.0055, 0.0065, 0.0072, 0.0059, 0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0052, 0.006, 
0.0045, 0.0056, 0.0055, 0.0059, 0.0063, 0.0061, 0.0053, 0.0077, 
0.0057), X82 = c(0.0068, 0.0064, 0.0058, 0.0065, 0.0074, 0.0063, 
0.0073, 0.007, 0.0078, 0.0066, 0.0062, 0.0083, 0.006, 0.0056, 
0.0068, 0.0074, 0.0072, 0.0059, 0.006, 0.0068, 0.007, 0.0062006200620062, 
0.0056, 0.0071, 0.0072, 0.007, 0.0069, 0.006000600060006, 0.0061, 
0.0066, 0.0068, 0.007, 0.0071, 0.0084, 0.0062, 0.0076, 0.0082, 
0.0063, 0.0047, 0.0065, 0.0068, 0.0061, 0.0058, 0.0056, 0.0073, 
0.0062, 0.007, 0.0056, 0.0063, 0.0062, 0.0072, 0.0068, 0.0067, 
0.0067, 0.0063, 0.0058, 0.0065), X83 = c(0.0253, 0.0237, 0.0229, 
0.0222, 0.0244, 0.0231, 0.0226, 0.0247, 0.0219, 0.0244, 0.0274, 
0.0213, 0.0233, 0.0229, 0.0188, 0.0214, 0.0231, 0.025, 0.0216, 
0.0224, 0.0245, 0.0291029102910291, 0.0221, 0.0244, 0.0214, 0.0227, 
0.0234, 0.0217021702170217, 0.024, 0.0193, 0.0204, 0.0218, 0.0221, 
0.0241, 0.0276, 0.0172, 0.0223, 0.0252, 0.0317, 0.0274, 0.0268, 
0.0226, 0.0289, 0.0229, 0.0253, 0.0248, 0.0261, 0.0233, 0.0219, 
0.0259, 0.022, 0.0221, 0.0213, 0.0265, 0.0207, 0.0243, 0.028), 
    X84 = c(0.0469, 0.0489, 0.0473, 0.0501, 0.0462, 0.0473, 0.0519, 
    0.0521, 0.0511, 0.0417, 0.0377, 0.0459, 0.0429, 0.048, 0.0563, 
    0.056, 0.0437, 0.0491, 0.0526, 0.0492, 0.0307, 0.037003700370037, 
    0.0507, 0.049, 0.0505, 0.0485, 0.0494, 0.0533053305330533, 
    0.0405, 0.0515, 0.0464, 0.0485, 0.0469, 0.0501, 0.034, 0.06, 
    0.0468, 0.0453, 0.049, 0.0432, 0.051, 0.0502, 0.0425, 0.0443, 
    0.045, 0.0383, 0.0476, 0.0476, 0.055, 0.0368, 0.0474, 0.0437, 
    0.0545, 0.0441, 0.0455, 0.0405, 0.0435), X85 = c(0.0069, 
    0.0055, 0.0057, 0.0044, 0.0072, 0.0066, 0.0056, 0.0066, 0.0054, 
    0.0056, 0.0066, 0.0066, 0.0078, 0.0068, 0.0052, 0.0059, 0.0063, 
    0.0067, 0.0063, 0.0047, 0.0072, 0.0066006600660066, 0.0058, 
    0.0066, 0.0057, 0.0069, 0.006, 0.0058005800580058, 0.0066, 
    0.0059, 0.0055, 0.006, 0.0064, 0.0056, 0.0085, 0.0035, 0.0053, 
    0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0074, 0.007, 0.0062, 0.0058, 0.0047, 0.0065, 
    0.007, 0.0067, 0.0046, 0.0047, 0.006, 0.0064, 0.0068, 0.0064, 
    0.0056, 0.0058, 0.0065, 0.007), X86 = c(0.027, 0.0271, 0.0339, 
    0.0287, 0.0323, 0.0286, 0.0288, 0.0291, 0.0288, 0.0316, 0.0308, 
    0.0329, 0.0275, 0.0287, 0.0294, 0.0276, 0.0306, 0.0297, 0.0284, 
    0.0319, 0.0329, 0.0325032503250325, 0.0294, 0.0333, 0.0289, 
    0.0273, 0.0275, 0.0273027302730273, 0.0335, 0.0252, 0.0259, 
    0.0288, 0.0262, 0.0323, 0.0308, 0.0233, 0.0257, 0.0303, 0.0303, 
    0.0315, 0.0307, 0.0284, 0.0265, 0.0306, 0.034, 0.0288, 0.0306, 
    0.0256, 0.0254, 0.031, 0.0303, 0.0284, 0.0272, 0.025, 0.0287, 
    0.0322, 0.0296), X87 = c(0.0207, 0.0188, 0.0222, 0.0206, 
    0.0214, 0.0219, 0.0214, 0.02, 0.0208, 0.0228, 0.0203, 0.021, 
    0.0186, 0.0181, 0.0184, 0.0213, 0.0217, 0.0225, 0.0199, 0.0212, 
    0.0197, 0.0176017601760176, 0.0208, 0.0191, 0.0193, 0.0198, 
    0.0189, 0.0212021202120212, 0.0228, 0.0199, 0.0192, 0.0243, 
    0.0211, 0.022, 0.0209, 0.0196, 0.022, 0.0213, 0.022, 0.0216, 
    0.0223, 0.0234, 0.0227, 0.0232, 0.0209, 0.0194, 0.0199, 0.0224, 
    0.0194, 0.0219, 0.0203, 0.0199, 0.0228, 0.0196, 0.022, 0.022, 
    0.0188), X88 = c(0.0228, 0.0193, 0.0203, 0.0187, 0.0197, 
    0.0209, 0.0182, 0.0218, 0.0189, 0.0193, 0.0208, 0.0226, 0.0224, 
    0.0199, 0.0201, 0.0193, 0.0211, 0.0205, 0.0174, 0.02, 0.0223, 
    0.0191019101910191, 0.0194, 0.0181, 0.0229, 0.0213, 0.0177, 
    0.0164016401640164, 0.0232, 0.0209, 0.0189, 0.0188, 0.0211, 
    0.0179, 0.0214, 0.0189, 0.0208, 0.017, 0.0198, 0.0179, 0.0172, 
    0.0194, 0.0195, 0.0206, 0.0198, 0.0222, 0.0171, 0.0203, 0.0185, 
    0.0184, 0.0197, 0.0192, 0.0188, 0.0183, 0.0191, 0.0197, 0.0189
    ), X89 = c(0.0066, 0.0062, 0.0087, 0.0085, 0.0073, 0.0057, 
    0.0074, 0.0068, 0.0064, 0.0077, 0.0088, 0.0085, 0.0074, 0.0071, 
    0.0058, 0.0065, 0.0068, 0.0062, 0.006, 0.0066, 0.0083, 0.0078007800780078, 
    0.0066, 0.0065, 0.0071, 0.0078, 0.0064, 0.0053005300530053, 
    0.0077, 0.006, 0.0064, 0.0061, 0.0083, 0.0078, 0.0063, 0.0059, 
    0.0064, 0.0068, 0.008, 0.006, 0.0064, 0.007, 0.007, 0.0064, 
    0.0065, 0.0082, 0.007, 0.0084, 0.0061, 0.0078, 0.0096, 0.0068, 
    0.0081, 0.0075, 0.0075, 0.0069, 0.0072), X90 = c(0.0093, 
    0.0119, 0.0084, 0.0078, 0.0095, 0.0085, 0.0075, 0.0097, 0.0089, 
    0.011, 0.0112, 0.0113, 0.0111, 0.0096, 0.008, 0.0102, 0.008, 
    0.0083, 0.0085, 0.0088, 0.0086, 0.01000100010001, 0.0092, 
    0.0105, 0.0088, 0.0068, 0.0109, 0.0108010801080108, 0.0113, 
    0.0089, 0.0085, 0.0108, 0.0077, 0.0093, 0.0093, 0.0096, 0.0107, 
    0.0112, 0.0102, 0.0107, 0.0102, 0.0092, 0.0088, 0.0084, 0.012, 
    0.0084, 0.0092, 0.0098, 0.0093, 0.0096, 0.0106, 0.0085, 0.0089, 
    0.009, 0.0103, 0.0102, 0.0098), X91 = c(0.0053, 0.0048, 0.0042, 
    0.0039, 0.0037, 0.005, 0.005, 0.004, 0.0057, 0.0061, 0.005, 
    0.0054, 0.0069, 0.0054, 0.0048, 0.0046, 0.004, 0.0057, 0.0053, 
    0.0044, 0.0047, 0.0049004900490049, 0.0051, 0.0055, 0.0055, 
    0.0043, 0.0051, 0.0048004800480048, 0.0034, 0.0061, 0.0047, 
    0.004, 0.0045, 0.0041, 0.0072, 0.0041, 0.005, 0.0059, 0.0057, 
    0.0053, 0.0048, 0.0046, 0.0046, 0.0052, 0.006, 0.0047, 0.0051, 
    0.0056, 0.0056, 0.0063, 0.0056, 0.0054, 0.006, 0.0055, 0.0055, 
    0.0045, 0.0048), X92 = c(0.0045, 0.0037, 0.0049, 0.0036, 
    0.0045, 0.0047, 0.0058, 0.0047, 0.0048, 0.0032, 0.0038, 0.0051, 
    0.0032, 0.0049, 0.0037, 0.0046, 0.0049, 0.0043, 0.0045, 0.0038, 
    0.0043, 0.0033003300330033, 0.0046, 0.0031, 0.0047, 0.0032, 
    0.0042, 0.006000600060006, 0.0043, 0.0042, 0.0048, 0.0034, 
    0.0043, 0.0048, 0.0039, 0.0057, 0.0038, 0.0052, 0.0061, 0.004, 
    0.0035, 0.0052, 0.0043, 0.0045, 0.0038, 0.005, 0.0048, 0.0039, 
    0.0049, 0.0041, 0.0057, 0.0043, 0.005, 0.0056, 0.0053, 0.0047, 
    0.0035), X93 = c(0.0078, 0.0078, 0.0059, 0.0071, 0.009, 0.0081, 
    0.0062, 0.0066, 0.0083, 0.0072, 0.0084, 0.0067, 0.0072, 0.0082, 
    0.006, 0.0068, 0.0068, 0.0059, 0.0074, 0.007, 0.0094, 0.008000800080008, 
    0.0071, 0.007, 0.0078, 0.0086, 0.0063, 0.007000700070007, 
    0.0069, 0.0078, 0.0073, 0.0077, 0.0083, 0.0066, 0.0087, 0.0053, 
    0.0074, 0.0085, 0.0062, 0.0079, 0.0056, 0.0064, 0.0076, 0.0078, 
    0.0074, 0.0092, 0.0071, 0.0069, 0.0079, 0.0076, 0.0075, 0.0079, 
    0.0064, 0.0081, 0.0064, 0.0069, 0.009), X94 = c(0.0095, 0.0078, 
    0.0086, 0.0079, 0.0074, 0.0083, 0.008, 0.0083, 0.0081, 0.0086, 
    0.011, 0.0099, 0.0075, 0.0094, 0.0084, 0.0081, 0.0075, 0.0094, 
    0.0106, 0.0088, 0.0076, 0.0097009700970097, 0.0092, 0.0082, 
    0.0082, 0.0082, 0.0082, 0.009000900090009, 0.008, 0.0096, 
    0.0072, 0.008, 0.009, 0.0087, 0.0087, 0.0077, 0.0086, 0.0088, 
    0.0093, 0.0081, 0.0091, 0.0083, 0.0075, 0.0099, 0.0084, 0.0084, 
    0.0084, 0.0079, 0.0098, 0.0092, 0.0091, 0.0083, 0.0086, 0.0077, 
    0.0086, 0.0092, 0.0099), X95 = c(0.0023, 0.002, 0.0028, 0.0031, 
    0.0027, 0.0026, 0.0026, 0.0031, 0.0032, 0.0023, 0.0036, 0.0031, 
    0.0033, 0.0019, 0.0036, 0.0035, 0.0024, 0.0035, 0.003, 0.0027, 
    0.0039, 0.003000300030003, 0.0018, 0.0024, 0.0032, 0.0029, 
    0.0028, 0.0036003600360036, 0.003, 0.0034, 0.0028, 0.004, 
    0.0033, 0.0024, 0.0027, 0.0037, 0.0029, 0.004, 0.0037, 0.0018, 
    0.0032, 0.0032, 0.0045, 0.0031, 0.0027, 0.002, 0.003, 0.0024, 
    0.0035, 0.0031, 0.0028, 0.0029, 0.0026, 0.0026, 0.0029, 0.0021, 
    0.0035), X96 = c(0.0023, 0.0031, 0.003, 0.0028, 0.0025, 0.0022, 
    0.0028, 0.0032, 0.0022, 0.0026, 0.0031, 0.0027, 0.0034, 0.0025, 
    0.0027, 0.0025, 0.0023, 0.0023, 0.0032, 0.003, 0.0029, 0.0027002700270027, 
    0.0026, 0.0028, 0.0024, 0.0028, 0.0026, 0.0026002600260026, 
    0.0023, 0.0024, 0.0033, 0.0027, 0.0023, 0.0022, 0.0021, 0.0027, 
    0.0023, 0.0023, 0.0017, 0.003, 0.0027, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0031, 
    0.0029, 0.0029, 0.0026, 0.0021, 0.003, 0.0032, 0.003, 0.0036, 
    0.0023, 0.0028, 0.0021, 0.0029, 0.0028), X97 = c(0.0047, 
    0.004, 0.0046, 0.0043, 0.0045, 0.0048, 0.0053, 0.0057, 0.0045, 
    0.0057, 0.0065, 0.004, 0.0054, 0.0051, 0.006, 0.0051, 0.0059, 
    0.0072, 0.0048, 0.0056, 0.0056, 0.0047004700470047, 0.0052, 
    0.0068, 0.006, 0.0051, 0.0059, 0.0062006200620062, 0.0064, 
    0.0057, 0.0051, 0.005, 0.0065, 0.0057, 0.0064, 0.0059, 0.0062, 
    0.0051, 0.0058, 0.0062, 0.0059, 0.0059, 0.0048, 0.0058, 0.0045, 
    0.0063, 0.005, 0.0042, 0.0053, 0.0067, 0.0058, 0.0062, 0.0059, 
    0.0059, 0.0052, 0.0066, 0.0061), X98 = c(0.022, 0.02, 0.0225, 
    0.0222, 0.0208, 0.0202, 0.02, 0.0199, 0.0173, 0.0177, 0.019, 
    0.022, 0.0211, 0.0206, 0.023, 0.0207, 0.0209, 0.0206, 0.0217, 
    0.0227, 0.0134, 0.0181018101810181, 0.0219, 0.021, 0.0205, 
    0.0212, 0.0183, 0.0219021902190219, 0.018, 0.0189, 0.0234, 
    0.021, 0.0187, 0.02, 0.0183, 0.0218, 0.0203, 0.0209, 0.0215, 
    0.0182, 0.0202, 0.022, 0.0197, 0.0173, 0.0183, 0.019, 0.0204, 
    0.019, 0.0216, 0.0178, 0.0224, 0.022, 0.0183, 0.0202, 0.0201, 
    0.018, 0.0202), X99 = c(0.0036, 0.005, 0.0035, 0.0035, 0.0044, 
    0.0043, 0.0038, 0.0037, 0.0049, 0.0028, 0.0036, 0.0039, 0.0033, 
    0.0045, 0.0043, 0.0042, 0.0046, 0.004, 0.0048, 0.0042, 0.0032, 
    0.0039003900390039, 0.0031, 0.0032, 0.0043, 0.0042, 0.0047, 
    0.0049004900490049, 0.0045, 0.0035, 0.0033, 0.0049, 0.0045, 
    0.0038, 0.0035, 0.0044, 0.0042, 0.0028, 0.0036, 0.0038, 0.0039, 
    0.0042, 0.0037, 0.0031, 0.0027, 0.0031, 0.004, 0.0038, 0.0055, 
    0.0041, 0.0036, 0.0049, 0.004, 0.0037, 0.0043, 0.0031, 0.0035
    ), X100 = c(0.004, 0.007, 0.0048, 0.0064, 0.006, 0.0066, 
    0.006, 0.0054, 0.007, 0.006, 0.0047, 0.0051, 0.0045, 0.0061, 
    0.0058, 0.0056, 0.0056, 0.0044, 0.0048, 0.0046, 0.0046, 0.006000600060006, 
    0.0036, 0.0053, 0.0067, 0.0058, 0.0051, 0.0064006400640064, 
    0.0045, 0.0052, 0.0063, 0.0054, 0.0057, 0.0049, 0.0052, 0.0067, 
    0.0069, 0.0062, 0.0064, 0.0051, 0.0051, 0.0047, 0.0067, 0.0049, 
    0.0056, 0.0066, 0.0064, 0.0056, 0.0062, 0.0055, 0.0045, 0.0051, 
    0.0053, 0.006, 0.0056, 0.0053, 0.0057), status = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X80", "X81", "X82", 
"X83", "X84", "X85", "X86", "X87", "X88", "X89", "X90", "X91", 
"X92", "X93", "X94", "X95", "X96", "X97", "X98", "X99", "X100", 
"status"), row.names = c(NA, 57L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I put this into e1071 using leave-one-out cross validation, I get inconsistent results, depending on whether I do

```
kernelfn <- "linear"
y.svm <- rep(NA, nrow(testdf))
for (i in 1:nrow(testdf)) {
    testset <- testdf[i, ]
    trainset <- testdf[-i, ]
    model.svm <-
        svm(
            **trainset$status**~.,
            data = trainset,
            type = "C-classification",
            kernel = kernelfn
        )
    y.svm[i] <- as.character(predict(model.svm, testset))
}
> table(testdf$status, y.svm)
   y.svm
     0  1
  0 17  9
  1 10 21
```

OR

```
kernelfn <- "linear"
y.svm <- rep(NA, nrow(testdf))
for (i in 1:nrow(testdf)) {
    testset <- testdf[i, ]
    trainset <- testdf[-i, ]
    model.svm <-
        svm(
            **trainset[,22]**~.,
            data = trainset,
            type = "C-classification",
            kernel = kernelfn
        )
    y.svm[i] <- as.character(predict(model.svm, testset))
}

> table(testdf$status, y.svm)
   y.svm
     0  1
  0 26  0
  1  0 31
```

Even though when I check this, they are identical.

```
> identical(testdf$status, testdf[,22])
[1] TRUE
```

Why this inconsistency, in predictions? Am I doing something wrong when doing the LOOCV?

Thanks

Comment: You are not specifying the model correctly in either case. The first call passes somehow, but the second does not pass as you expect it. To see what I am saying use `as.character(predict(model.svm, testset[,1:21])` in both cases. The 2nd model uses `status` as a feature.